# Truncation error when inserting varchar into varbinary table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm getting a "String or binary data would be truncated" error when executing the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO sen.varbinary_table 
VALUES ('TypicalBinaryABCD',CONVERT(varbinary(255),'0xABCD'));
```

I'm fairly new to SQL but I don't think it's a syntax error.

Appreciated any help!

EDIT 1:

```
CREATE TABLE sen.varbinary_table (KeyColumn VARCHAR (255), Column1 varbinary(255));
```

Comment: Please supply the `create table` so we can see column lengths and positions. Also just use `0xABCD` it shouldn't be in quotes.

Comment: Any triggers on the table?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the suggestion. I've removed the quotes but the same error is still generated.

Comment: No triggers exist for this table

Comment: it's not the syntax: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/026fa/3

Comment: what are the results of `select * from sys.tables where object_id = object_id('sen.varbinary_table')` and `select * from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('sen.varbinary_table')`?

Comment: Awesome hint Laurence!!! When I ran the second query, it showed that Column1 had a maximum length of only 1...no idea how and why... So I dropped the table and created it again. Now the query works. Thanks.

Comment: If you forget to specify a size for a varbinary column, it defaults to 1